# java exec return PID in Windows

Tags: java, windows

In linux I can run:

```
System.exec('echo test & echo $1');
```

Which will return the process ID of the command I have executed. How can a similar aproach be translated into Windows? Allowing me to execute a command and return its PID.

Just to be clear I am not looking for the PID of my JAVA application. I am looking for the process ID of an external application spawned by JAVA using `System.exec`.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add why you need this? Maybe there's a better solution that'll work for all OSes.

Comment: I want to be able to track the process id of the application even if Java terminates. So that the PID in question maybe terminated later. I am currently looking at enumerating over the process list to see which was the last to start but I'm not sure how reliable of a solution this will be, even though $! carries out the same function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Question was not regarding returning the PID of the java process but rather external applications. In the end I had to use C++ to iterate through the system processes sorting by their start time to return the latest process.

Answer (score 0):

try jps - Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool

jps

18027 Java2Demo.JAR

18032 jps

18005 jstat

Comment: The command executed doesn't look like it's going to be a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

One solution use the RuntimeMXBean. The name of the bean contains the pid (ex. 12345@localhost).

Warning : The returned name string can be any arbitrary string and a Java virtual machine implementation can choose to embed platform-specific useful information in the returned name string.

On the Sun JVM (Windows plateform), the PID is present.

```
String processName =
  java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
System.out.println(processName.split("@")[0]);
```